# The page is not displayed correctly in Django prodject, maybe because of uncorrect views

Tags: python, html, django, django-views

So, I did a Django project according to the Django textbook. And when I typed

> python manage.py runserver

I saw this page:
[image]

It's not what I wanted to see. There should be a list of latest questions, because I type it in index file(
I think taht the problem is in views or in html files.

*polls/views.py:*

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.template import loader
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, render
from django.shortcuts import redirect
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import Http404
from django.views import generic
from django.utils import timezone

from . models import Answer, Question


class IndexView(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'polls/index.html'
    context_object_name = 'latest_question_list'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Question.objects.filter(
            pub_date__lte=timezone.now()
        ).order_by('-pub_date')[:5]

class DetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Question
    template_name = 'polls/detail.html'
    def get_queryset(self):
        return Question.objects.filter(pub_date__lte=timezone.now())


class ResultsView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Question
    template_name = 'polls/results.html'


def vote(request, question_id):
    question = get_object_or_404(Question, pk=question_id)
    try:
        selected_answer = question.answer_set.get(pk=request.POST['answer'])
    except (KeyError, Answer.DoesNotExist):
        # Redisplay the question voting form.
        return render(request, 'polls/detail.html', {
            'question': question,
            'error_message': "You didn't select a answer.",
        })
    else:
        selected_answer.votes += 1
        selected_answer.save()
        # Always return an HttpResponseRedirect after successfully dealing
        # with POST data. This prevents data from being posted twice if a
        # user hits the Back button.
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('polls:results', args=(question.id,)))
```

*polls/index.html*

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Тест</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'polls/main.css' %}" />
</head>
<body>

<h1>Доступные вопросы</h1>

{% if message %}
    <p><strong>{{ message }}</strong></p>
{% endif %}

{% if latest_questions_list %}
    <ul>
        {% for question in latest_questions_list %}
            <li>
                <a href="{% url 'polls:detail' question.id %}}">{{ question.question_text }}
                </a>
            </li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% else %}
    <p>No questions are available right now.</p>
{% endif %}
</body>
</html>
```

What did I do wrong?
I'm new at django, so don't judge me please :(

Comment: Simply a typo: you set `context_object_name = 'latest_question_list'` yet in your template you write `latest_questions_list` (notice the extra `s`).

Comment: Oh, I didn't even notice. I corrected it, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This part is not clear. Why exactly you use the  `__lte` option for the latest Question instances. I mean why not `Question.objects.order_by('-pub_date')[:5]` ?

```
def get_queryset(self):
    return Question.objects.filter(
        pub_date__lte=timezone.now()
    ).order_by('-pub_date')[:5]
```

Comment: I think the OP has Questions that can be set to be published in the future so they are showing only the published Questions in this view.

Comment: In the textbook, there was something about future time of questions, so I used this code instead of just `Question.objects.order_by('-pub_date')[:5]`

Comment: So, I wrote `Question.objects.order_by('-pub_date')[:5]` and corrected the mistake with extra "s", and the code started working in the right way. Thank you a lot, guys!